# Run only selected command / line

Tags: powershell

let's say that I have following Powershell script that contains severall powerhsell commands

```
Get-Service -Name  BITS
Get-Service -Name WinDefend
Get-Service -name Winmgmt
Get-Service -Name WdNisSvc
```

How can I make my script like that that it would ask which of 4 commands it would run like

```
Select which command you would like to run:

1. Get-Service -Name  BITS
2. Get-Service -Name WinDefend
3. Get-Service -name Winmgmt
4. Get-Service -Name WdNisSvc
```

and they based of my selection it will run only wanted command

EDIT: I was now able to solve problem this far but now issue is that: how do I prompt these to user so user can select them and save the answer so I can use it after *"Write-Host "Now we can perform [$input]""*

```
 $input = Read-Host -Prompt 'Select what operation you want to perform'
 
 1. Get-Service -Name  BITS
 2. Get-Service -Name WinDefend
 3. Get-Service -name Winmgmt
 4. Get-Service -Name WdNisSvc
 
     if ($input) {
      Write-Host "Now we can perform [$input]"
        **here should then answer be executed**
     } else {
         Write-Warning -Message "No input selected"
     }
```

Comment: Look up `Read-Host` and `switch` for starting points.

Comment: Use a switch statement

Comment: Also provide a way out if the user wants to quit, (add an option like `Q. Quit`)

Comment: @vonPryz I made some edits to my original post. What would be next good step to proceed?

Comment: Do **NOT** use `$input` as self-defined variable as this is an [Automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7#input) in PowerShell. Choose another name for that var. Also, write the menu lines out **before** asking for user input, then (as @vonPryz commented) use a [switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch) to perform the chosen action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a menu like below.

If you're interested in learning what's being applied on the menu:

- [`about Do`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_do?view=powershell-7.2)
- [`Matching Operators`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#matching-operators)
- [`about_Switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch?view=powershell-7.2)

```
$services = @(
    'BITS'
    'WinDefend'
    'Winmgmt'
    'WdNisSvc'
)

$servCount = $services.Count

do
{
    # Phrase this correctly so it's clear user should select a Number
    'Select a Service you would like to query:'
    
    $services | ForEach-Object -Begin { $i = 1 } -Process {
        "$i. $_"; $i++
    }

    switch -Regex($selection = Read-Host)
    {
        "^[1-$servCount]{1}$" {
            Get-Service $services[$selection-1]
            'Press ENTER to continue...'
            Read-Host
            Clear-Host
            break
        }
        "Q" { break }
        Default { Write-Warning 'Invalid Selection!' }
    }
}
until($selection -eq 'Q')
```